# CGRect not changing during animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cgrect

I'm animating an UIView and want to check if its frame intersects with another UIView's frame. This is how I "spawn" one of the UIViews:

```
- (void) spawnOncomer 
{    
oncomer1 = [[Oncomer alloc] initWithType:@"car"];
    [self.view addSubview:oncomer1];


    //make the oncomer race across the screen
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; {
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        CGRect f = oncomer1.frame;
        f.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height+oncomer1.frame.size.height;
        oncomer1.frame = f;
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(decountCar)];
    } 
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

So far so good. Now I want to check if this UIView and my other UIView collide by doing this:

```
- (void) checkCollision {

    bool collision = CGRectIntersectsRect(car.frame, oncomer1.frame);
    if (collision) {
        NSLog(@"BOOOOOOOM");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Oncomer: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(oncomer1.frame));
    }

}
```

However, they never collide. Although I see oncomer1 moving across the screen, loggin oncomer1.frame never changes: it keeps outputting `Oncomer: {{50, 520}, {30, 60}}`(which are the post-animation values).

Does anyone know why this is?

P.s. Both methods are called directly or indirectly with a NSTimer and are thus performed in the background

Comment: What does NSLog(@"Oncomer: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(oncomer1.frame)); output after the animation is complete?

Comment: That value. I figured out that that is the post-animation value. The `oncomer1.frame`is set to this value as soon as the animation starts..

Comment: I think it may be a good idea to look at the center of the view as opposed to the frame during an animation. Why not try making a rect based on the center point in your checkCollision method to see if that works? First though, try NSLogging the center point to see if it changes during the animation.

Comment: Actually, just try replacing the .frame with .bounds and see if that works.

Comment: Didn't work. oncomer1's bounds are always: {0, 0}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIView` geometry updates apply immediately to their `CALayer`, even in an animation block.  To get a version of a layer with animations applied, you can use `-[CALayer presentationLayer]`, like this (warning - untested code):

```
- (void) checkCollision {
    CGRect oncomerFrame = oncomer1.layer.presentationLayer.frame;
    bool collision = CGRectIntersectsRect(car.frame, oncomerFrame);
    if (collision) {
        NSLog(@"BOOOOOOOM");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Oncomer: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(oncomerFrame));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
CGRect f = oncomer1.frame;
f.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height+oncomer1.frame.size.height;
oncomer1.frame = f;
```

A logical explanation of the frame never changing is that you are only changing the `y` of the frame, and you are always setting it to the same value determined by two `height`s.